# Code to Kill current Excel file, then Export to new Excel file without opening output file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a database that is linked to a few others.  The db in question has some script that exports a table to an Excel ".xlsx" with a name that is linked to other databases.  Basically data entry is done in one db and then the other db pulls in the information live so we have real time updating.

However, after the kill sequence completes and the new file is exported, the Excel file opens up.  This causes a problem with the second db not being able to see real time updates since the new export file does not actually overwrite the previous since the previous has opened automatically. I need help telling the Excel export files not to open.

I know I should Dim the file name but I haven't :-).

Below is the code, any help is much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

'Delete Existing File First; then create new
On Error Resume Next
Kill "\\ct13nt003\MFG\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT2Updated.xlsx"
On Error GoTo 0
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SMT2Export", "\\ct13nt003\MFG\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT2Updated.xlsx", True
```

Comment: Have any of the answers below resolved your problem? If so, please mark one as accepted...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That code has `On Error Resume Next` just before `Kill xlFileName`.  That means if the `Kill` fails for any reason, it will fail silently.

I have no idea whether that issue contributes to your problem, but suggest you try it this way instead.

```vb
'Delete Existing File First; then create new
'On Error Resume Next
If Len(Dir(xlFileName)) > 0 Then
    Kill xlFileName
Else
    ' xlFileName does not exist; no Kill required
End If
'On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I have the 'On Error Resume Next' line in there to skip the step just in case the file is not present (which may be the case from time to time).

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not the `kill` but the fact that the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method *opens* the file.  There is no oprion/argument to prevent the file from opening, so I think its simply necessary to force the file to close immediatwly after this,  per my suggestion above.

Comment: @DavidZemens That's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @user2887400 if my answer helped you,  please consider making it as the "accepted" answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here since I don't really do VBA in Access but I do a lot with Excel so try something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
Const xlFileName as String = "\\ct13nt003\MFG\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT2Updated.xlsx"
Const shortFileName as String = "SMT2Updated.xlsx"
Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xlWb as Object 'Excel.Workbook

'Delete Existing File First; then create new
On Error Resume Next
Kill xlFileName
On Error GoTo 0

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SMT2Export", xlFileName, True

'Get the Excel Application
Set xlApp = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
'Get the specific workbook
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks(shortFileName)
'Close the workbook
xlWb.Close
'Quit Excel (if needed)
'xlApp.Quit

'Clean up
Set xlWb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Subscript Out of Range Error**

Use the file's name instead of the full path with the `xlApp.Workbooks` method, per revision above.

There is another potential reason for this error, but this is the most likely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback David.  I keep throwing a Run-Time error 9 on the line "Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks(xlFileName)"

Comment: @user2887400 See revision above. Let me know if that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your scenario, I'm stumped since I've never had that kind of problem with "Killing" a file.  Maybe like another users suggested, you should turn off "On Error  Resume Next", at least until you figure out why this error is happening.

Another suggestion would be to try a different deletion method, like

```
myFSO.DeleteFile "\\ct13nt003\MFG\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT2Updated.xlsx"
```